# Объединить [шаблоны] с [шаблоны-проектирования]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Пересмотрел вопросы с метками [шаблоны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b) и [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Таких нет, везде, где [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) - [шаблоны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b) заменены на [шаблоны-с++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%81%2b%2b).

В связи с этим предлагаю изменить описание [шаблоны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b), выбросив упоминание о С++, и объединить их с [шаблоны-проектирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) (а если как-то можно - переименовать, чтоб просто [шаблоны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b) вообще не было).

И оставить только две метки - [шаблоны-проектирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) и [шаблоны-с++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%81%2b%2b)

P.S. Обсуждение засохло, как обычно, не родив ничего умного.

Ладно, с [шаблоны-с++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%81%2b%2b) я когда-то лично справился - ввёл такую метку и исправил все просто [шаблоны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b) на [шаблоны-с++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%81%2b%2b), где это было надо.

Но объединить две метки я лично не могу - там какие-то траблы начинаются, что эта метка уже объединена etc - кто там имеет соответствующую возможность, сделайте, а?...

Comment: imho это совсем разные вещи. Шаблоны проектирования это всякие обсерверы и посетители от банды четырех, а шаблоны С++ это vector<int> ... и т.п.

Comment: @avp Еще раз и медленно. Сейчас в описании метки "шаблоны" написано, что ее можно употреблять и для шаблонов проектирования, и для шаблонов С++. При том, что для шаблонов С++ она не употреблена - я как-то прочищал. Поэтому и предлагаю слить ее с "шаблонами проектирования", чтоб не запутываться. Потому что это и в самом деле разные вещи. И оставить только две метки - "шаблоны проектирования" и "шаблоны С++".

Comment: Тогда этот резюм -- *`И оставить только две метки - "шаблоны проектирования" и "шаблоны С++"`* явно и пропишите (с  этим согласен)

Comment: по-моему вполне логичное предложение.

Comment: Куда засунуть шаблоны WPF? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/888029/

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Где они здесь? (описание метки "шаблоны"): "Шаблоны (Шаблоны проектирования, паттерны проектирования, Design Patterns, ) - представляют собой подход к проектированию чего-либо. Не являются готовым решением, а лишь представляют общее описание решения проблемы, которое можно использовать в различных ситуациях. В ООП широко используются 23 паттерна.
На сайте исторически используется и для пометки вопросов, имеющих отношение к templates C++."? Как эту метку можно цеплять к шаблонам WPF? Если это существенно - надо делать третью метку, imho.

Comment: @Harry WPF это просто пример. Я к тому, что синонимизировать как есть нельзя, это только увеличит хаос, так как в метке полно вопросов не по шаблонам проектирования. Описание метки в текущем виде бесполезно, и его лучше бы вообще удалить.

Comment: Хорошо бы предложения в виде отдельных ответов опубликовать. Будет проще обсуждать.

Comment: Пинганите меня на выходных. Подробнее посмотрю, что там с этими метками.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Пингую :)

Comment: @Harry посмотрел. В целом согласен с Вадимом. [tag:шаблоны] нужно выпилить. Надо постепенно пробежаться по вопросам с этой меткой и убрать её с них и, если надо, вместо неё добавить более подходящую по надобности. Синонимизировать явно не стоит.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica "Шаблоны" в применении к C++ я и так регулярно чищу; в применении к другим темам не могу считать себя достаточно подкованным для принятия решений...

Comment: @Harry на enSO тоже есть метка [шаблоны](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/templates/info). Там в описании рекомендуют использовать более конкретные метки, типа [tag:django-template].

Comment: @Harry я буду постепенно эту метку разгребать, но, опять же, как и у вас, не по всем вопросам квалификации хватает.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Взгляните еще на "олимпиада" (больше 80 раз, без описания) и "олимпиады" - ни разу, но с описанием :) Описание к "олимпиаде" я добавил, но не стоит ли теперь убрать "олимпиады" совсем?

Comment: @Harry скорее, их нужно объединить.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Ну объедините... :) Кстати, я у себя в знаках посмотрел и, несмотря на имеющиеся ответы, в списке знаков олимпиад нет. Это так и задумано или какая-то ошибка? Типа https://ibb.co/zrsSqdp

Comment: @Harry я такое же по некоторым другим меткам видел. Больше похоже на баг.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica К кому обращаться? :)

Comment: @Harry на MSE, думаю, стоит задавать вопрос сразу. Но, есть вероятность, что там уже такой вопрос был. Если не хотите сами смотреть, пинганите меня на выходных, посмотрю.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Лучше пингану. У меня с английским так себе, читать могу, но писать - увольте...

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Опять пингую. Я навскидку посмотрел несколько меток - например, олимпиада, сложность, итераторы - их нет. Причем явно нет и каких-то еще, но я уже не стал копать сильнее, в надежде, что если баг - то исправлен будет для всех :)

Comment: @Harry https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343735/260198

Comment: @Harry по метке должно быть более 100 вопросов задано всего, только после этого можно будет её трекать.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica OK

Answer (score 5):

Я считаю, что вопросы по метке [шаблоны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b) являются просто свалкой самых разных тем, которые в основной массе связаны с интерфейсом пользователя, который может иметь какой-то шаблон. И объединять эти вопросы с меткой [шаблоны-проектирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) неверно по этой причине, несмотря на схожее описание метки, так как пользователи используют её по-другому. Проблема также в том, что по-английски шаблоны могут быть как и templates (её скорее в этом смысле используют), так и patterns.

Поэтому хорошо было бы либо

- удалить метку вообще, так как она напоминает мета-метку, собирая разные понятия
- обновить описание метки, указав все возможные случаи её использования и удалив ненужные